# Execute 'docker run' from within SBCL Common Lisp

Tags: docker, command-line, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to run a function in my lisp program. It is a bot that is connected to an IRC channel and with a special command you can query the bot to evaluate a simple lisp command. Because it is extremely dangerous to execute arbitrary code from people on the internet I want the actual evaluation to happen in a VM that is running a docker for every evaluation query the bot gets.

My function looks like this:

```lisp
(defun run-command (cmd)
  (uiop:run-program (list "docker" "run" "--rm" "-it" "my/docker" "sbcl" "--noinform" "--no-sysinit" "--no-userinit" "--noprint" "--disable-debugger" "--eval" (string-trim '(#\^M) (format nil "~A" cmd))) "--eval" "'(quit)'") :output '(:string :stripped t))
```

The idea behind this function is to start a docker that contains SBCL, runs the command via SBCL --eval and prints it to the docker std-out. And this printed string should be the result of `run-command`.

If I call

```
docker run --rm -it my/docker sbcl --noinform --no-sysinit --no-userinit --noprint --disable-debugger --eval "(print (+ 2 3))" --eval "(quit)"
```

on my command line I just get 5 as an result, what is exactly what I want.

But if I run the same command within lisp, with the `uiop:run-program` function I get

```
Subprocess #<UIOP/LAUNCH-PROGRAM::PROCESS-INFO {1004FC3923}>
 with command ("docker" "run" "--rm" "-it"
               "my/docker" "sbcl" "--noinform"
               "--no-sysinit" "--no-userinit" "--noprint"
               "--disable-debugger" "--eval" "(+ 2 3)")
```

as an error message, which means the process failed somehow. But I don't know what exactly could be wrong here. If I just execute for example "ls" I get the output, so the function seems to work properly.

Is there some special knowledge I need about `uiop:run-program` or am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: So it turns out that the -it flag caused issues. After removing the flag a new error emerges. Now the bot has not the permissions to execute docker. Is there a way to give it the permissions without granting it sudo rights?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the error message? this seems truncated. is there anything else printed on `*error-output*`?

Comment: Note: your goal reminds me of the [cl-isolated](https://github.com/kanru/cl-isolated) library.

Comment: coredump what follows after the error message is the stack trace, I could provide it if it helps.

Ehvince this looks very promising. But how do they prove that their subset is secure?

Comment: @Echon: I wouldn't use cl-isolated unless you essentially already trust your code: there are no resource controls for one thing.  In your case have you tried things like running `type docker` &c to check paths are correct?

Comment: @tfb I checked all the paths, everything works as intended. I found out that the -it flag caused problems. Now my problems shifted, like I described in the edit of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the `-it` did cause trouble. After removing it and elevating the correct permissions to the bot everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's, probably, something wrong with the way docker is invoked here (or SBCL). To get the error message, invoke `uiop:run-program` with `:error-output :string` argument, and then choose the `continue` restart to, actually, terminate execution and get the error output printed (if you're running from SLIME or some other REPL). If you call this in a non-interactive environment, you can wrap the call in a handler-bind:

```
(handler-bind ((uiop/run-program:subprocess-error
                 (lambda (e) (invoke-restart (find-restart 'continue)))))
  (run-command ...))
```

Comment: I tried to get an error message in the way you described and I got "the input device is not a TTY" as a result. Now I am even more clueless. But maybe it can help debugging. Edit: Somehow the -it flag created the error. After removing the flag I get the following error: "Unable to find image 'my/docker:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my/docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denie...[sly-elided string of length 272]"